# How to limit a for loop in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have this code below, however I only want it to show a maximum of 15 characters in the string.  How do I do this?

```
string star = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Model.orgInternalcontact.User.Password.Length; i++)
{
     string mem = "*";
     star = star + mem;
}
```

Comment: A one liner: `string star = new string('*', Math.Min(15, Model.orgInternalcontact.User.Password.Length))`

Comment: What are you want to do?

Comment: @vcsjones That doesn't work, as you're using `Math.Max` rather than `Math.Min`.

Comment: @Ruirize I already fixed it.

Comment: Note that in the for loop, for every run the Model.orgInternalcontact.User.Password.Length gets evaluated, thus instead if you know that the length is not going to change, you should initialize a variable with that value instead if.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string star = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Model.orgInternalcontact.User.Password.Length && i < 15; i++)
{
     string mem = "*";
     star = star + mem;
}
```

You can have any conditional statement in the second part of a for.

Comment: Won't that actually be... sixteen characters? =)

Comment: Maaaaaaaaaybe. At least, not anymore.

Answer (score 4):

```
string star = new string('*', 
     Math.Min(Model.orgInternalcontact.User.Password.Length, 15));
```

Comment: +1 for removing the clunky and inefficient string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

```
string star = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Model.orgInternalcontact.User.Password.Length && i < 15; i++)
{
     string mem = "*";
     star = star + mem;
}
```

You can have multiple comparisons in your statement.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
string star = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(15, Model.orgInternalcontact.User.Password.Length); i++)
{
     string mem = "*";
     star = star + mem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but i'll go for the other as its shorter.  But thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string star = "";
string mem = "*";
var count = Math.Min(15, Model.orgInternalcontact.User.Password.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
{
     star = star + mem;
}
```